# How can I properly use generics in a master class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class called Team, from which derive three other classes called FootballTeam, BasketballTeam and VolleyballTeam. In the base class I have a method to calculate the result of a match between two teams, but I need a way to properly use generics in order to avoid teams of different sports to play against each other. I'm obviously doing something wrong here but I cannot figure it out.

Base class:

```
public abstract class Team<T extends Team<T>> {

    protected String teamName;
    protected Integer won = 0;
    protected Integer lost = 0;
    protected Integer tied = 0;
    protected Integer played = 0;

    public void matchResult(T opponent, Integer homeScore, Integer awayScore) {
        if (homeScore > awayScore) {
            won++;
        } else if (homeScore < awayScore) {
            lost++;
        } else {
            tied++;
        }

        played++;

        if (opponent != null) {
            opponent.matchResult(null, awayScore, homeScore);
        }
    }

}
```

Derived classes:

```
public class FootballTeam extends Team {

    public FootballTeam(String teamName) {
        super(teamName);
    }

    // code
}

public class BasketballTeam extends Team {

    public BasketballTeam(String teamName) {
        super(teamName);
    }

    // code
}

public class VolleyballTeam extends Team {

    public VolleyballTeam(String teamName) {
        super(teamName);
    }

    // code
}
```

Another solution would be to implement the matchResult method in every subclass, but that wouldn't follow the DRY principle.

Comment: `public class FootballTeam extends Team<FootballTeam>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

Have a `Sport` interface/abstract class:

```
interface Sport {

}
```

and three classes that implement `Sport`:

```
class Football implements Sport {}
class Basketball implements Sport {}
class Volleyball implements Sport {}
```

Now you can have a `Team<T extends Sport>`:

```
public abstract class Team<T extends Sport> {
```

The `matchResult` method needs to be changed to:

```
public void matchResult(Team<T> opponent, Integer homeScore, Integer awayScore) {
```

Your concrete team classes will be declared like so:

```
public class FootballTeam extends Team<Football> { ... }
public class BasketballTeam extends Team<Basketball> { ... }
public class VolleyballTeam extends Team<Volleyball> { ... }
```

With this design, `FootballTeam` can't play against `BasketballTeam`, but can play against `Team<Football>`, which I think makes sense. Right? At runtime, a `Team<Football>` has to be a `FootballTeam` unless you write more classes.

The slightly ugly thing about this is that you now have this weird `Team<Sport>` type, but you can't create an instance of it anyway, unless you write more classes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to model a Match inside a Team. Maybe you need a Match class?

```
public class Match {

 private Team teamOne;
 private Team teamTwo

 public Match(Team one, Team two) {
   if (one == null || two == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("one or both teams are Null");
   }
   if (!one.getClass().equals(two.getClass()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both teams must be of the same type");
   }
   this.teamOne = one;
   this.teamTwo = two;
 }

 public Team winner() {
  // here you can determine which team wins depending on their class
  if (one instanceof FootballTeam) {
   // ... calculate the winner of a football match
  } 
  // else calculate the winner of the other possibilities

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) and [Lonny Ono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13318289/lonny-ono) for answering. In the end I decided to create a League class and implement the matchResult method inside it:

```
public class League<T extends Team> {

    ArrayList<T> teams;

    public League() {
        this.teams = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addTeam(T team) {
        if (!teams.contains(team)) {
            teams.add(team);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void printLeagueDetails() {
        for(T team : teams) {
            team.printTeam();
        }
    }

    public void matchResult(T homeTeam, T awayTeam, Integer homeScore, Integer awayScore) {
        if (homeScore > awayScore) {
            homeTeam.won++;
            awayTeam.lost++;
        } else if (homeScore < awayScore) {
            homeTeam.lost++;
            awayTeam.won++;
        } else {
            homeTeam.tied++;
            awayTeam.tied++;
        }

        homeTeam.played++;
        awayTeam.played++;
    }

}
```